# Retrieve firebase hashmap data in POJO

Tags: java, android, hashmap, firebase, pojo

I used an `ArrayList` to store data on `Firebase`.It got stored as a `HashMap` with key value starting from 0 and its value stored as string.

The database is as follows:

[image]

I am using `POJO`, to store and retrieve data.

My `POJO` is defined as follow:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class POJO_MemoriesRVDisplay {
    String mem_name;
    String mem_place_street_address;
    HashMap<Object,Object> images;

    public POJO_MemoriesRVDisplay() {
    }

    public HashMap<Object, Object> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(HashMap<Object, Object> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public POJO_MemoriesRVDisplay(String mem_name, String mem_place_street_address, HashMap<Object, Object> images) {
        this.mem_name = mem_name;
        this.mem_place_street_address = mem_place_street_address;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getMem_name() {
        return mem_name;
    }

    public void setMem_name(String mem_name) {
        this.mem_name = mem_name;
    }

    public String getMem_place_street_address() {
        return mem_place_street_address;
    }

    public void setMem_place_street_address(String mem_place_street_address) {
        this.mem_place_street_address = mem_place_street_address;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error such as:

```
Failed to bounce to type
```

How do I declare the `POJO` properly.  I have tried several posts but couldn't help it. Tried changing the declaration of images to strings, still wouldn't work. Please help!

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: The "Failed to bounce to type" has a "caused by" clause that will tell you the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the Hashmap Declaration. Initially declaring it as

```
Hasmap<Object, Object> images;
```

didn't work in the POJO but after hours of trial and error I deleted the POJO and restarted the system. When I recreated the POJO file, I declared the Hashmap as:

```
Hashmap images;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution:

```
//First create your object    
POJO_MemoriesRVDisplay pojo = new POJO_MemoriesRVDisplay("School", "12345", Your hashmap);  

//Create your reference where you want to store your data       
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();   

//Save your data   
root.push().setValue(pojo);
```